# React Native doesn't show array.map details

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to display a list of users using a **.map** but the I can't see anything in the screen (*just the first message Hello React Native*) and I don't get any error. I have try to show in the console the list of users and the users appear in the console corretly.

Here is the code.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';

type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      users: []
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({
      users: [{
          name: 'Name 1',
        },
        {
          name: 'Name 2',
        }, {
          name: 'Name 3',
        }
      ]
  })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Text>Hello React Native</Text> 
        {this.state.users.map(user => {
          {console.log(user)} // Displaying the users properly in the console.
          <View>
            <Text>
              {user.name}
            </Text>
          </View>
        })}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `return` statement is missing from the `.map` function, you have to add that

```
render() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Text>Hello React Native</Text> 
      {this.state.users.map((user, index)=> {
        {console.log(user)} // Displaying the users properly in the console.
        return (
         <View key={index}>
          <Text>
            {user.name}
          </Text>
         </View>
        )
      })}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Hope this will help!